# Images height bug in ios

Tags: html, ios, css

I have a problem with the height of images in the "products" part of my website [www.takchinsaffron.com](http://www.takchinsaffron.com). The height isn't set in iOS. It hasn't any bug on other devices.

```
.grid figure{
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is it the css code that set height of products image?

Comment: .grid figure img {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 min-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
}

Comment: What is it the size of your images? Try to set a fixed height to the img element and show me what happends

Comment: i can't set a fixed hight to every device in responsive. i had tried it before

Comment: Ok I think that the problem is 'min-heigth: 100%' because on my iphone 5s i see images with height equal to the height of my device. Like that image fill heigth of parent div (100% of device). Try to work with css of parent div of images

Comment: change 'min-heigth: 100%' to 'min-heigth: auto' and all works fine. If height is auto and width is some value, image maintains is aspect ratio. And if you have for example a width of 50px, heigth will be 50px. On iOS, images with heigth of 100% become heigth of device (I dont now why)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change `min-height: 100%` to `min-height: auto` and all works fine.
Check that CSS does not set the height of the image to 100%.

If height is auto and width is some value, image maintains its aspect ratio.

And if you have, for example, a width of 50 pixels, height will be 50 pixels.
On iOS, images with height of 100% become height of device (I don't know why).

Answer (score 31):

My parent had `display: flex` so I had to put `align-self: flex-start` on the image.

```
image {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: Any explanation, why does it happen?

Comment: I'd love to know why this works but hey, at least it does ^^

Comment: maybe they have a `bottom:0px; top:0px;` going on

Comment: this is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

For me, using only `width: inherit` on the image element resolved the issue.

For reference, my parent has the following properties:

```
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column; 
    width: 9vh;
    height: 9vh;
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. My solution was to add:

```
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%; 
 min-width: 100%;
```